# Find density of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm homelearning probability and trying to solve the following problem:

> The density of a random variable $\mathbb{X}$ is $f(x)=c*(x+\sqrt{x}), 0<x<1$
>
> Determine the density of a random varible $\mathbb{Y}=\frac{1}{\mathbb{X}}$. What are the values of the random variable $\mathbb{Y}$?

These are my steps so far:

$P(\mathbb{X}<x)= P(\frac{1}{\mathbb{Y}}<x)=P(\frac{1}{x}<\mathbb{Y})=P(-\frac{1}{x}>-\mathbb{Y})$

I want to calculate the density using derivate, but I am stuck at that point because I am not sure how.

Could you help me?

Comment: Figure out $c$. Compute $P[Y \le x]$. Differentiate. What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @copper.hat $c=\frac{6}{7}$ and $f(x)=F_x'(x)=(-F(\frac{1}{X}))' = -(F'(-\frac{1}{x^2}))$. I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ takes values in $(0,1)$, $Y=1/X$ takes values in $(1, \infty)$.

Denote the CDF of $Y$ by $F_Y$. Then
$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P(1/X \leq y) = P(X\geq 1/y) = 1- P(X<1/y) = 1- F(1/y).$$
We then take the derivative:
$$f_Y(y) = F'_Y(y) = f(1/y)/y^2.$$

Comment: Thanks! $f(y)/y^2=\frac{6}{7}*\frac{1}{y^2+y}$? Also the boundaries for the random variable $\mathbb{Y}$ are $\mathbb{R} \setminus $ {$0$}?

Comment: Dont you get $f(1/y)/y^2$ ?

Comment: @jeea Hi, are you responding to my comment or to Dasherman's answer?

Comment: @Petra Dasherman's answer, I thought that following his answer, when we derivate $1-F(1/y)$ what we will get?

Comment: The second last $y$ should be ${1 \over y}$.

Comment: You're right, I corrected it!